# Оптимизация однотипного кода в С#. (Аргументы и конструкторы)

Tags: c#, оптимизация

Встал передо мной вопрос об оптимизации своего кода.

у меня много подобных строчек

```
            GenerateCar(car2, bestWay);
            GettingBest(moneyChange, car2, propuski, bestWay);
            GenerateCar(car3, bestWay);
            GettingBest(moneyChange, car3, propuski, bestWay);
            GenerateCar(car4, bestWay);
            GettingBest(moneyChange, car4, propuski, bestWay);
```

Я невероятно хочу запихнуть это дело в цикл и написать GenerateCar(car+i, bestWay),но видимо так не принято в С#.В этой и вопрос,как это делается?

и второй вопрос,про конструкторы.

```
        int[] car0 = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        int[] car1 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] car2 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] car3 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] car4 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] car5 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] car6 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] car7 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] car8 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] car9 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

это режет глаза.) конструктор ругается от такого кода:

```
class Car
{
    int[] massivchik;

    public Car()
    {
        this.massivchik = massivchik;
    }
}
```

не работает,в общем подскажите а как бы вы заменили эти тексты с массивами?

Answer (score 3):

Заместо кучи массивов carN вам было бы неплохо завести список массивов cars:

```
// объявление
List<int[]> cars = new List<int[]>();
// инициализация
for (int i = 0; i < количествоМашин; i++)
    cars.Add(new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 });

// генерация
for (int i = 0; i < количествоМашин; i++)
{
    GenerateCar(cars[i], bestWay);
    GettingBest(moneyChange, cars[i], propuski, bestWay);
}
```

"Компилятор ругается от такого кода:" - правильно ругается, ведь вы пытаетесь приравнять неинициализированное поле класса к самому себе.

```
class Car
{
    int[] massivchik;

    public Car()
    {
        // в этот момент времени massivchik = null
        this.massivchik = massivchik;
    }
}
```

Конструктор надо переделать в один из двух вариантов:

```
public Car()
{
    array = new int[заранееИзвестнаяПостояннаяДлинаМассива];
}
```

либо

```
public Car(int[] array)
{
    this.array = array;
}
```

И да, пожалуйста, переименуйте переменные в что-нибудь достойное. :) Приятно, конечно, что сейчас они носят исконно-русские названия, но вы же не на ЯП 1С пишете.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код можно переписать вот так

```
var cars = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                .Select(x=>Enumerable.Range(0,10)
                .ToArray())
            .ToArray();

foreach(var car in cars)
{
    GenerateCar(car, bestWay);
    GettingBest(moneyChange, car, propuski, bestWay);
}
```